# PHP for loop counting issue

Tags: php

Hi There I am hoping that someone can help me with this php issue.

i would like to get the number into the form from this Loop function

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    echo '<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="100" rows="10">'.spin($string, false).'</textarea>';
    echo '<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="100" rows="10">'.spin($string, false).'</textarea>';
}
```

any idea on how I can implement it as to number the textarea(s) from 1 to 100

Thanks

Comment: Hi Zneak - yes similar to an id tag... if i can print out like

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
etc... up to 100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string concatenation `.`, a number will be automatically converted to a string:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    echo '<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea' . $i . '" cols="100" rows="10">'.spin($string, false).'</textarea>';
}
```

Or if you want to actually display the number:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    echo $i . '. <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea' . $i . '" cols="100" rows="10">'.spin($string, false).'</textarea>';
}
```

*If this is not what you want to have to clarify what you want.*

---

**Note:** An ID has to be unique for any HTML element. In your code, you generate 100 textareas with the same ID.

Comment: Thanks Felix this is exactly what I looked for... I tried to do it as .i. but not with the $ :-)...

Comment: @Gerald Ferreira: You're welcome. Variables always start with `$` ;)

Comment: Note: An ID has to be unique for any HTML element. In your code, you generate 100 textareas with the same ID.

I am using asp but needed a php function. Now I can submit the 100 texarea's to my php and pick up the values there!